# Tone Generator in Lazarus for OS X

Tags: macos, audio, real-time, lazarus

How should I go about to create a tone generator in Lazarus for Mac?

I can't seem to find anything about this on the internet?

No Wav-file related stuff or TProcess related stuff please.

Things need to run in realtime here.

Basically I'd like to be able to play SIN waves and output them through the speakers.

Comment: Have you looked at CoreAudio's audio units?

Comment: @rocky No I haven't I will look at it!

Comment: I got something to work with Mac OS X afplay using TProcess, but that's not what I am looking for due to timing issues.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to understand **[FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform)** (Fast Fourier Transformation) and **[Inverse FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Expressing_the_inverse_DFT_in_terms_of_the_DFT)** (search for u_fft.pp in your FPC sources directory). Using Inverse FFT can generate sine waves, after what you need to determine if you will play them in real time or play via intermediate WAV. Maybe some library like this one can help:
http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/uos
http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,17599.0.html

Alternative and much simpler way would be to generate sine waves of different frequencies, add them and divide by number of channels (if you have a need to play more frequencies at once).

Comment: Hey, thanks! I don't understand how to install UOS to try it out. Do you have some info on how to get it up and running?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have OS X. You should try in forum or contact the author.

Comment: I can't get it to work, I don't know how to install it.